# Simultaneous finetuning and network modification in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

How can I add or remove layers from pre-trained inception module, and learn the weights of new layers, and finetune the weights of pre-trained layers?

Ex. Remove the softmax and add one LSTM layer after inception module.

Comment: Could you please link the exact module that you have in mind?